# AWs Batch ECS. Cannot get more than 16jobs in parallel despite quota increase

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-batch

Hoping someone has experienced similar limitations/quota insights

We cannot get more than 16 jobs running in our AWS batch in environment, and cannot figure out where the limit is coming from

We are running AWS Batch using containers on ECS on EC2 based compute environment, as detailed below.

- containers need a GPU. (This is all configured and working).
- Each EC2    has 1 GPU and 4 VCPU. (g3s.xlarge)
- ComputeEnv is set to Min CPUs 0, Desired Cpus 104, Max Cpus 256
- have requested and had approved a limit of 256 G based cpus.
- max ec2 instances running is 16 (which tallies based on 64 limit of jobs and 4cpu per container)

**The max jobs is always limited to 16. (which equates to 64vcpu) I've searched all quotas and can't find any other restrictions? (Vpcs? etc) what am i missing**

note we have plenty of avail ip addresses in our vpc (1024)

thanks as always in advance.
B

Compute Env extract from template:

```
Type: AWS::Batch::ComputeEnvironment
Properties:
  Type: MANAGED
  ComputeEnvironmentName: !Sub "${StackName}-ECSComputeEnv"
  ComputeResources:
    Type: EC2
    MinvCpus: 0
    DesiredvCpus: 104
    MaxvCpus: 256  # 4 vcpu per 24hr + 4 extra for download indices, in future diff ec2 instance
    InstanceTypes:
    - g3s.xlarge
```

Full cloudformation template here: https://tmpsend.com/jQg8zww0

Comment: Do you have other EC2 instances running out of batch ? Maybe you are reaching your limit on the total number of VCPUs.

Comment: How long are the jobs? Batch is tuned to place jobs that run at least 3 to 5 minutes